# ndk-build gstreamer android tutorial: cannot find -lrt

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, gstreamer

I am following the tutorial at 
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development

I would like to use `ndk-build` to build the example.

When I use `"ndk-build"`, there is an error message.
Here are the output messages:

---

```
GStreamer      : [GEN] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c

GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c

GStreamer      : [LINK] => gst-build/libgstreamer_android.so
```

`/home/quanta/tools/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lrt`

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [buildsharedlibrary] Error 1

---

I use ndk-r9d in ubuntu linux 64bit 12.04

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Add Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial-1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-1.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-    build/
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := coreelements
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk
```

Comment: Can you show your Android.mk?

Comment: Try  replace to: LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid $(APP_LDLIBS)

Answer (score 0):

> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

to

> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have a librt. It's all in libc.

Presumably `include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk` is adding `-lrt` to ldlibs.